# Filter customized range of cells

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003

I have a several tables of cells (they are just ranges not tables) . I was wondering if it is possible to create a filter option for each of these ranges. Example place a data filter for cells K13:K22. I realised that the filter can only be implemented for one range at a time . I was wondering if there is an easier way to programme a data filter for each of the ranges , so as to make it more convenient. Came across something like this online but it only focuses at a certain value. Some help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

```
Sheets("Base data").Select

    'If Data Filter is already active on this worksheet
    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:=Range("H82").Value


    'If Data Filter is NOT active on this worksheet
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:=Range("H82").Value
```

Comment: Given that a filter really only increases the visibility of certain values, would [Conditional Formatting](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) be sufficient?

Comment: Okay basically i have a table of values showing different periods, with values of financial ratios corresponding to the periods.These values are plotted in graphs. So i want to only see certain periods to track the progress of the ratios. Not all periods all the time. That is why i need a filter @Jeeped

Comment: Do you happen to use XL 2013? You can filter graphs there. Anyways, it is still a little bit unclear. Could you site simple examples on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I am using 2003 unfortunately:/ @L42

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can have multiple filters in one sheet, so answer is no.
[Here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-excel/can-you-have-multiple-filter-tables-on-one-sheet/f9b617b0-25a4-439f-9212-0649754855b7) is discussion about same question, with option to use custom views, but I think it's not what you want